# Node.js reports "Use-After-Free" vulnerability with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I started a new npm repo (running in an official node docker container), installed the puppeteer package, and got a "high" severity vulnerability warning:

```
# node --version
v15.13.0
npm --version
7.8.0
# npm list
puppeteer@1.0.0 /home/node/puppeteer
`-- puppeteer@8.0.0
# npm audit
# npm audit report

puppeteer  <1.13.0
Severity: high
Use-After-Free - https://npmjs.com/advisories/824
fix available via `npm audit fix`


1 high severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
```

The puppeteer package version is obviously greater than 1.13.0, but it still warns about this "Use-After-Free" vulnerability. Needless to say, `npm audit fix` doesn't fix anything. What's going on?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue